# Remove single quote character escaping

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this

```
This is\' it
```

I would like it to look like this

```
This is' it
```

Nothing I do seems to work

```
> "This is\' it".replace(/\\'/,"'");
'This is\' it'
> "This is\' it".replace("'",/\\'/);
'This is/\\\\\'/ it'
> "This is\' it".replace("\'","'");
'This is\' it'
> "This is\' it".replace("'","\'");
'This is\' it'
```

UPDATE: This is a little hard to wrap my head around but I had my example string inside an array something like.

```
> ["hello world's"]
[ 'hello world\'s' ]
```

It automatically happens like so:

```
> var a = ["hello world's"]
undefined
> a
[ 'hello world\'s' ]
> a[0]
'hello world\'s'
> console.log(a[0])
hello world's
undefined
> console.log(a)
[ 'hello world\'s' ]
undefined
>
```

Comment: `console.log("This is\' it")` returns `This is' it` for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None of your test strings actually contain backslashes. The string you are inputting each time is: `This is' it` because the backslash escapes the single quote.

Your first (regex-based) solution is almost perfect, just missing the global modifier `/\\'/g` to replace all matches, not just the first. To see this in action, try the following:

```
> "This is\\' it"
"This is\' it"
> "This is\\' it".replace(/\\'/g,"'");
"This is' it"
```

Comment: `"This is\\' it".replace(/\\'/g,"'");` returns `'This is\' it'`. My string is actually from JSON and is `'This is\' it'`.

Comment: If that's the JSON string, then it should be unescaped automatically just by parsing the JSON. `'This is\' it'` is a single-quoted string with a single quote inside, the backslash "disappears" when the string is read.

Comment: yes your are right, I updated my question and it all makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
"This is\' it".replace(/\\(.?)/g, function (s, n1) {
    switch (n1) {
    case '\\':
        return '\\';
    case '0':
        return '\u0000';
    case '':
        return '';
    default:
        return n1;
    });
```

Taken from http://phpjs.org/functions/stripslashes:537

Answer (score 0):

I think the first option in your question works. When you mention it as a string in JavaScript, you need to escape the `\` so that it is read as a string rather than a special character.
Check this jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/T7Du4/2/